# Open tui imageeditor in a modal

Tags: popup, bootstrap-modal, toast-ui-image-editor

hello i search a solution to load tui image editor in a html modal
i have a form with many image, i want to add a button to edit it, and it will be open a modal with image inside ...
my idea is to add script in page and js event in button ... but i don't known how
some on can help me ?

```
         // Image editor
         var imageEditor = new tui.ImageEditor('#tui-image-editor', {
             includeUI: {
                 loadImage: {
                     path: 'img/sampleImage2.png',
                     name: 'SampleImage'
                 },
                 theme: blackTheme, // or whiteTheme
                 initMenu: 'filter',
                 hideHeader: 1,
                 menuBarPosition: 'bottom'
             },
             cssMaxWidth: 700,
             cssMaxHeight: 500,
             usageStatistics: false
         });
         window.onresize = function() {
             imageEditor.ui.resizeEditor();
         }
        </script>
```

Regards